# Getting data from JSON and adding this element into $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need add element, which I get in JSON format into array as $scope.array
My code is:

```
$scope.sections=function(){
    $scope.array=[];

    $http.get("/app/query/?mod=find&type=all").success(function(data){

        $.each(data, function(i, row){
            $scope.array.push('aaa');
            console.log(row);
        });


    });
    return $scope.array;
}
console.log($scope.sections());
```

But this functions returned empty array, How can I add elements to `$scope.array`?

This string adds data to consol correctly `console.log(row);` , but `$scope.array.push` is not work

Comment: This is due to async nature of call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually modify it to be something more like this

```
$scope.sections=function(){
  return $http.get("/app/query/?mod=find&type=all").then(function(resp){
      var array = [];
      angular.forEach(resp.data, function(row, i){
          array.push(row);
          console.log(row);
      });
      return array;
  });
};
$scope.array = $scope.sections();
$scope.array.then(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

In this case, we simply return the entire promise from the function. Now $scope.array is a promise, rather than a raw value.

Before returning the promise we do an extra then function to manipulate the return value. We want to convert it to an array so that any future users of the promise will see it resolve to array rather than an object. You can do any transformation that you need here I'm simply taking the logic from your question.

Keep in mind that now your code will have to know how to deal with a promise, rather than an array, but this way you can ensure the value is always resolved. If you do need to bind this to the UI, using interpolation or otherwise, angular will automatically resolve the promise. For example

```
<div>{{array}}</div>
```

in your markup would automatically resolve to the array that gets created when it's ready. No extra code needed.

Answer (score 3):

As `$http` is async it will return a empty array, because it takes time to get the data from the server, that's why `console.log(row)` returns the data correctly.

Also you need to call `$scope.$apply()` in order to apply the new data to the scope.

```
 $scope.sections=function(callback){
  $scope.array=[];

  $http.get("/app/query/?mod=find&type=all").success(function(data){
       var temp = [];
       $.each(data, function(i, row){
          temp.push('aaa');
          console.log(row);
       });

       $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.array = temp;
       });        

       callback($scope.array);
   });
 }

 $scope.sections(function(result) { console.log(result); });
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use scope.$apply inside of the callbacks with the $http service. There's also really no point in creating your own callback argument when you can just return the promise itself. AngularJS handles promises very nicely internally, and will automatically resolve them for you when they are ready. You are adding an unnecessary layer on top of functionality which is already there in the promise object. See my answer below for what I mean.